# WAS7 System Properties in RAD 7.5.1

Tags: websphere, rad

I have an old project in WSAD 5.1.2 with a WAS4 server configuration that's in a .wsi-file. If I double click it I get the server configuration editor and on the environment tab there is a System Properties section with some name-value pairs.

Now I have opened the same project in RAD 7.5.1. Where can i input the same name-value pairs for a server in RAD 7.5.1? There's no "environment-tab" if I double-click my server, just an "Overview" tab.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I finally found the proper way of doing it in the admin web interface...

Application servers > myServer > Process definition > Java Virtual Machine > Custom properties

Answer (score 1):

In RAD 7.5.4 JVM name value pair is stored in Servers --> Application Servers --> java and process Management --> process definition --> java virtual machine --> custom properties

here you can create a new name value pair which can be used by Java code using System get properties function.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently IBM started to ship a real application server starting with RAD/RSA6 instead of the test server that comes with WSAD. So to configure the appserver it's just to use the web admin interface as usual.

Thanks to Jeanne Boyarsky for the answer in the forums over at [The Java Ranch](http://www.javaranch.com/).

The old app I'm porting needs some properties in the system properties of the JVM set so that they can be retrieved with System.getProperty(...) and I found a dirty way of making it work. So, until I find out how to do it the proper way, if there is a proper way, I came up with this hack:

After doing some "find" and "grep" in the profile directory of the appserver i found a file called:
`runtimes\base_v7\profiles\<profilename>\config\cells\<cellname>\nodes\<nodename>\servers\<servername>\server.xml`

At the bottom of server.xml there is a `<jvmEntries xmi:id="JavaVirtualMachine_....` tag.

Inside it you can add system properties tags on the format:
`<systemProperties xmi:id="someId" name="name of your property" value="the value" required="false"/>`

Anyone who knows how to to this the proper way and has read all the way down here must be crying by now... :)
But, it seams to work...